# Log Outgoing Apache Port on AJP Connection

Tags: logging, tomcat, mod-jk, ajp

I have Tomcat 7 set up to work with mod_jk and AJP. I'm wondering if, on the Tomcat side, I can log the mod_jk (Apache side) outgoing port with the Tomcat request handler thread name in order to track end-to-end network traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remote port number is available to your application in the environment variable `JK_REMOTE_PORT`.

There's no corresponding `JkRequestLogFormat` string to log the remote port, but it can be logged in a standard Apache mod_log_config request log with `%{remote}p` in `LogFormat`.